# Find the orders of all elements in the group $D_3×Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So to start, I know that the order of an element in a group is the power that it needs to be raised to in order to equal the identity element - i.e., for $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$, the element 6 will have an order of 10 because 6^10 is the first time that it mods to 1. I'm not sure how to do this with a cross group, and I'm not sure what Q is, since it is not indicated that it is the rationals

***Edit*** $D_3$ is in fact the dihedral group of order 6, and $Q$ in this case is the quaternions

Comment: If the question uses $Q$ without giving a definition in that question, then the definition of $Q$ is probably available in the index or the symbolic index of the relevant textbook.

Comment: $Q$ is probably the quaternion group of order 8, $D_3$ is the dihedral group of  order 6?

Comment: Edited, but both of you were correct - I checked the textbook I'm using again, and the author uses $Q$ for the quaternions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rationals are commonly denoted by the blackboard $\mathbb{Q}$. The group $Q$ is probably a subset of the quaternions, namely: $Q=\{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$ (8 elements total). $D_3$ is probably the dihedral group, which consists of: $D_3=\{\rho^0, \rho^1, \rho^2\}\cup \{s, \rho s, \rho^2 s\}$ (the symmetries of a triangle in the 2D plane, with $\rho^n$ $n$-rotations and $s$ a reflection).

If we have a direct product of two groups, we can denote an element by a tuple: $a\in D_3$ and $b\in Q$ give $(a, b)\in D_3 \times Q$. With their group operation defined as: $(a, b), (c, d)\in D_3 \times Q$ gives $(a, b)\circ (c, d)=(ac, bd)$. The $\circ$ is sometimes dropped.

If we have an element $(a, b)\in D_3\times Q$, suppose it has order $m$. Then, $(a, b)^m=(a^m, b^m)=(\rho^0, 1)$. What condition must $m$ satisfy for this to hold?

Answer:

> $m$ must satisfy $m=\text{lcm}(\text{ord}(a), \text{ord}(b))$.

I think with this in mind, you are able to check the cases of all the elements in this direct product.

I hope this helps.

**Edit**: There is actually a corollary of Lagrange's theorem, which states that the order of an element $x\in G$ must be a divisor of the order of $G$. This can be useful for checking the plausibility of a found order. However, note that the converse statement is not generally true.

Comment: Thanks! From what you've said, I think the order of each element is either 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, or 24, yes? Is there a simple way to check which elements have which order, or do I have to go through all 48 elements and check?

Comment: There is actually a nice corollary (from Lagrange's theorem), which states that the order of an element must be a divisor of the order of the group, which is nice to check the plausibility of your answer. As for your questions: We know that in $Q$ the orders are 1,2,4 and in $D_3$ it is 1,2,3. So the $\text{lcm}$-combinations give: 1,2,3,4,6,12. So not 24. You have to go through all 48 elements, but you can speed up by grouping elements of the same order, giving only 6 combinations.